# How to linearize this multiplicative constraint?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, disciplined-quasiconvex-programming

I have a constraint in the form

$\sqrt{|\sum_{c\in C}{h_cw_c}|^2}\ge\sqrt{x}\zeta$

Here, $h_c$ is s row vector (know), $w_c$ is a column vector (variable).
$x$ and $\zeta$ are also optimization variables.

How can I transform this into linear/convex constraint?

Also, I have $\text{imag}(h_cw_c)==0$.

Of course, I can write the LHS part as $||\sum_{c\in C}\rm{h_cw_c}||_2\ge\sqrt{x}\zeta$.

Now, how to deal the RHS part?

Is there any way to linearize this?

Comment: Are any of the variables binary? Otherwise, i think you're out of luck - face it, you have a non-convex nonlinear problem, and you're not going to cram this into CVX, if that is your hope, without a lot of bastardizations.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, unfortunately..no. if not exact linearization, may be some convex overestimation is possible?

Comment: Just use a non-convex solver. Try using YALMIP if you like the MATLAB environment. It handles problems CVX does in a similar, but not exactly the same, manner, and, unlike CVX, also can do non-convex problems and non-DCP convex problems, using either local or global optimization solver. The global solvers will do any under or overestimation for you, better than you would do on your own.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, does YALMIP support binary variables? I have binary variable in other constraints of my problem?

Comment: Yes, using solvers which natively support binary and integer, as well as its own top-level solvers, BNB (for convex problems) and BMIBNB for global solution of non-convex problems. You can use BMIBNB and specify FMINCON as upperesolver to globally optimize mixed-integer nonlinear non-convex problems (even though FMINCON does not support binary or integer problems, BMIBNB only feeds it continuous problems which it can handle.

Comment: I made a few edits to your MathJax. Please check that I didn't break anything.